# How to point ref to the document that includes another document in a Sphinx project?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a directory of restructuredtext files.

Index.rst has a :ref: to a section in table.rst.

table.rst is included in Footnotes.rst using the .. include:: directive.

After Sphinx renders the files as html, the link in Index.html points to table.html, instead of Footnotes.html.  How can I get the link to point to Footnotes.html, where table.html is included?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
:doc:`Footnotes.rst`
```